# C++ Protobufs :: How to erase particular field with MergeFrom()?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

First of all: I'm not an expert in protobuf.

Suppose I have such message structure:

```
package msg_RepAndOpt;

message RepAndOpt
{
    repeated string name = 1;
    optional string surname = 2;
    ...
    // there are lots of others.
}
```

And I have two components that have copies of this message:

```
// component1:
RepAndOpt A;
A.add_name("Name");
A.set_surname("Surname");

// component2:
RepAndOpt B;
```

In my case components modify those messages via transaction mechanism. It means that if one component changes some field it also sends it to another component to propagate those changes. Component-receiver is doing merge:

```
// Component2 modifies B and sends it to component1.
// Component1 perfoms merge:
A.MergeFrom(B);
```

Now, say, component2 wants to erase field "name".
If it will send clear B message (default construction) than:

- MergeFrom() will not modify A;
- CopyFrom() will erase also other fields.

Another way will be to fill B with the contents of A, clear name field and component1 will use CopyFrom().
But this is not acceptable because system is really high-loaded and there could be lots of other fields. 
So, desired solution to clean name field is:

1. Component2 create B message.
2. Explicitly stores information that it want to erase only name field.
3. Component1 perform A.MergeFrom(B).
4. Result: A::name is cleared but other fields are left untouched.

As far as I tested this applies to repeated and optional fields.
Is there any ready-to-use solution or I should modify protobuf implementation?

Comment: How about setting `B.name` to some special value ("DELETE_ME"), do a normal merge, but then scan through all fields and delete those whose value is the special one?

Comment: Yes. That's a possible solution. Good thing is that it does not require changes in protobuf implementation.
But I also should choose such special value for other types, for example int32. Here it's more difficult. It will be a big switch that detects the type of the field and then compares with the special value.

Comment: Yes, you'll need one such value for every type that you wish to support. Overloading should provide an easy way to program that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin protobuf solution for your case. The obvious solution would be to iterate over all the fields in message A and check if that field is present in message B, if not you could clear it.

Comment: But in this case if I will send clear B message, all fields of A will be cleared, right? But I only want to clear one field.

Comment: Yes, there is no way to mark a field as to be cleared. If you have complete control over the message types you could add a repeated string field which contains the fields which you want to clear.

Comment: Yes, but I already have in mind situation when I need to remove some values from repeated field. Not completely erase it.
Say I have {1,2,3} and I want to remove {2}.

Comment: For this case you would need something like change sets which tell the receiving component what needs to be done. If both components can change the same time and/or are not completely kept in sync i see no clean way to handle your cases otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve this with basic `MergeFrom()`, but you may want to check out these from the protobuf library:

https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/util/field_mask_util.h

In particular `FieldMaskUtil::MergeMessageTo()` seems to do what you want. You'll need to construct a `FieldMask` specifying exactly which fields you're interested in, so that other fields are left untouched.

Comment: Hi Kenton,
Can't figure out how to use it. Can you please give me a small example?

Comment: Ok. I managed to use it:

in *.proto file I added:
`google.protobuf.FieldMask field_mask = 3; `

on sender side (*.cpp) :
'B.mutable_field_mask()->add_paths("name");'

on receiver side (*.cpp):
'if (B.has_field_mask())
{
 FieldMaskUtil::MergeOptions megreOpt;
 megreOpt.set_replace_repeated_fields(true);
 FieldMaskUtil::MergeMessageTo(B, B.field_mask(), megreOpt, &A);
}'

This require proto v3.
@Kenton, Please check my version with proto v2 below.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** updated after comments from Kenton Varda (see below).

Expanding one of the previous answers:

There is a way to solve it by adding new field in message definition (this works for proto v2):

```
    repeated int32 fields_to_copy = 15;
```

This field will be filled by ID's of fields that would be copied (not merged) on the reciever side.

I also implemented this helper function:

```
// CopiableProtoMsg.hpp

#pragma once

#include <google/protobuf/message.h>

template <typename T>
void CopyMessageFields(const T& from, T& to)
{
    const ::google::protobuf::Descriptor *desc = T::descriptor();
    const ::google::protobuf::Reflection *thisRefl = from.GetReflection();

    std::vector<const ::google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor*> fields;
    int size = from.fields_to_copy_size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      const ::google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor *field = desc->FindFieldByNumber(from.fields_to_copy(i));
      fields.push_back(field);
    }
    T msgCopy(from);
    thisRefl->SwapFields(&to, &msgCopy, fields);
    to.clear_fields_to_copy();
}
```

This function checks fields_to_copy field and perform copying (via SwapFields()).

Here is the simple test:

```
RepAndOpt emulateSerialization(const RepAndOpt& B)
{
    RepAndOpt BB;
    std::string data;
    B.SerializeToString(&data);
    BB.ParseFromString(data);
    return BB;
}

TEST(RepAndOptTest, additional_field_do_the_job_with_serialization)
{
    RepAndOpt A;
    RepAndOpt B;

    A.add_name("1");
    A.add_name("2");
    A.add_name("3");
    A.set_surname("A");

    B.add_name("1");
    B.add_name("3");
    B.add_fields_to_copy(RepAndOpt::kNameFieldNumber);

    RepAndOpt recvB = emulateSerialization(B);
    A.MergeFrom(recvB);
    CopyMessageFields(recvB, A);

    EXPECT_EQ(2, A.name_size());
    EXPECT_STREQ("1", A.name(0).c_str());
    EXPECT_STREQ("3", A.name(1).c_str());
    EXPECT_TRUE(A.has_surname());
    EXPECT_EQ(0, A.fields_to_copy_size());
}
```

Comment: Don't override `MergeFrom()`. You will break parts of the protobuf implementation that expect `MergeFrom()` to work a certain way. Instead, put your reflection-based code as a stand-alone function -- there is no reason it specifically needs to be in the `MergeFrom()` method, since you can have your code that calls this call the new function instead. Also this way you don't have to user inheritance at all.

Comment: Right!
Thank you, @Kenton!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding approach with field masks (that was proposed by Kenton Varda):

*Note: This solution requires proto3, however the original message can be declared with proto2 syntax. [(link to proof)](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#using-proto3-message-types)*

We can define a field mask field:

```
import "google/protobuf/field_mask.proto";

message RepAndOpt
{
    repeated string name = 1;
    optional string surname = 2;

    optional google.protobuf.FieldMask field_mask = 3;    
}
```

And here is the test usage:

```
RepAndOpt emulateSerialization(const RepAndOpt& B)
{
    RepAndOpt BB;
    std::string data;
    B.SerializeToString(&data);
    BB.ParseFromString(data);
    return BB;
}

void mergeMessageTo(const RepAndOpt& src, RepAndOpt& dst)
{
    dst.MergeFrom(src);
    if (src.has_field_mask())
    {
        FieldMaskUtil::MergeOptions megreOpt;
        megreOpt.set_replace_message_fields(true);
        megreOpt.set_replace_repeated_fields(true);
        FieldMaskUtil::MergeMessageTo(src, src.field_mask(), megreOpt, &dst);
    }
}

TEST(RepAndOptTest, fix_merge_do_the_job_with_serialization_multiple_values)
{
    RepAndOpt A;

    A.add_name("A");
    A.add_name("B");
    A.add_name("C");
    A.set_surname("surname");

    RepAndOpt B;
    B.add_name("A");
    B.add_name("C");
    B.mutable_field_mask()->add_paths("name");
    mergeMessageTo(emulateSerialization(B), A);

    EXPECT_EQ(2, A.name_size());
    EXPECT_STREQ("A", A.name(0).c_str());
    EXPECT_STREQ("C", A.name(1).c_str());
    EXPECT_STREQ("surname", A.surname().c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar use case and ended up implement my own mixture based on  that @Denis' answer.

Although the language was Golang, which doesn't have FieldMaskUtil with MergeOptions.

```
            RepAndOpt.A.name RepAndOpt.B.name
 remove     ["A", "B", "C"]  ["A"]      => remove: A, keep: B, C
 add        ["A", "B", "C"]  ["D"]      => add:    D, keep: A, B, C
 add/remove ["A", "B", "C"]  ["A", "D"] => remove: A, add:  D, keep: B
```